# Which compression (is GZIP the most popular) servlet filter would you suggest?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I am looking for a GZIP servlet filter to be used in a high volume web-app. I doesn't want to use the container specific options.

Requirement

1. Ability to compress response payload (XML)
2. Faster
3. Proven in production for high volume applications
4. Should properly set appropriate **Content-Encoding**
5. portable across containers
6. Optionally able to decompress request

Thank you.

Comment: *And content length*? That's going to be memory hogging. Just let it to be sent in chunks, like everyone does.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for clarifying this. You are correct. I will remove this from the post.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this looks very promising for compression of CSS and JS: http://wro4j.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From what i've seen, most people generally use the gzip compression filter. Typically from [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).

The GZIP filter implementation is: [net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/ehcache/trunk/web/web/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/web/filter/GzipFilter.java)

The Maven coordinate for including it in your project is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

You will also need to specify an SLF4J logging target. If you don't know what this is or don't care slf4j-jdk14 or slf4j-simple works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: any specific reason why this is preferred?

Comment: could just be word of mouth. or that a lot of projects already use ehcache. either way, it has always seemed reliable and quick.

Comment: This worked great for me. I just added links to the mentioned implementation for anyone else trying this out who has not heard of ehcache.

Comment: How is it possible to apply GzipFilter only to some specified mime typeS? (SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061482/apply-ehcache-gzipfilter-to-specific-mime-types)

Comment: @Xdg You might need to extend the GzipFilter to do that.

Comment: If you only use the `GzipFilter` from `ehcache-web` and want to avoid bloating your app, you can exclude `ehcache-web`'s transitive dependency `ehcache-core` in your `pom.xml` like so
`<exclusions><exclusion><artifactId>net.sf.ehcache></artifactId><groupId>ehcache-core</groupId></exclusion>`

Comment: net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter in method doFilter() - seems like this filter stores full request/response data in a memory - which can cause memory problems with large requests (or big file uploads).

Answer (score 21):

The GZIP filter that I use to compress resources in my webapps:

```java
public class CompressionFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String acceptEncoding = httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING);
        if (acceptEncoding != null) {
            if (acceptEncoding.indexOf("gzip") >= 0) {
                GZIPHttpServletResponseWrapper gzipResponse = new GZIPHttpServletResponseWrapper(httpResponse);
                chain.doFilter(request, gzipResponse);
                gzipResponse.finish();
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

}

public class GZIPHttpServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private ServletResponseGZIPOutputStream gzipStream;
    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;

    public GZIPHttpServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    }

    public void finish() throws IOException {
        if (printWriter != null) {
            printWriter.close();
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
        if (gzipStream != null) {
            gzipStream.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (printWriter != null) {
            printWriter.flush();
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.flush();
        }
        super.flushBuffer();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (printWriter != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("printWriter already defined");
        }
        if (outputStream == null) {
            initGzip();
            outputStream = gzipStream;
        }
        return outputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("printWriter already defined");
        }
        if (printWriter == null) {
            initGzip();
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(gzipStream, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()));
        }
        return printWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentLength(int len) {
    }

    private void initGzip() throws IOException {
        gzipStream = new ServletResponseGZIPOutputStream(getResponse().getOutputStream());
    }

}

public class ServletResponseGZIPOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

    GZIPOutputStream gzipStream;
    final AtomicBoolean open = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    OutputStream output;

    public ServletResponseGZIPOutputStream(OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        this.output = output;
        gzipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(output);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (open.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            gzipStream.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        gzipStream.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        write(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (!open.get()) {
            throw new IOException("Stream closed!");
        }
        gzipStream.write(b, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (!open.get()) {
            throw new IOException("Stream closed!");
        }
        gzipStream.write(b);
    }

}
```

You also need to define the mapping in your web.xml:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.my.company.CompressionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The formatting of this code is not perfect, but it actually works for me, without any dependency. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thank you for providing full implementations for all the classes, I prefer this small solution to importing a whole new dependency (which comes with a bunch of dependencies of its own).

Question, why do map to js/css/html/jsp specifically, what types of streams would you not want to compress?

Comment: Images, executable files or any other file type that will not take advantages of compression.

Comment: Please not that this could break `If-Match` support, unless `ETag` doesn't get managed (usually with a `-gzip` suffix).

Comment: Would be much appreciated if there were implementations of `isReady()` and `setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener)` in ServletResponseGZIPOutputStream. 
These methods came with Servlet 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the pjl-comp-filter CompressingFilter:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjl-comp-filter/

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use something in-front of tomcat to off-load gzipping.  Apache with mod_deflate will perform well.  You have the option of putting apache on the same box, or moving it off to a different box, that way compression doesn't impact your app at all.  mod_jk or mod_proxy will both work fine in this setup.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: I want this solution to be portable so this is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: How do you know he's using Tomcat?  I use Jetty, which is a full web server, and they don't recommend putting Apache in front of it.

Comment: @jmort253 - there are several other reasons you might want to use apache in front of jetty. e.g. might be for load balancing several jetty instances.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're using Nginx in front see here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html. But definitely, as Zeki said it is better to move this to the dedicated web server.