# JSP gzip output stream

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, gzip, outputstream

I know I can gzip the output stream by using something like..

```
OutputStream outA = response.getOutputStream();
outWriter = new PrintWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(outA), false);      
response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
outWriter.println(.....);
outWriter.close();
```

in a JSP, but is it possible to write it as:

```
OutputStream outA = response.getOutputStream();
outWriter = new PrintWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(outA), false);      
response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
%>
...
```

I know this is done in PHP for example by capturing the output buffer before it is flushed, gzipping the buffer, and then finally writing it.

But is it possible in a JSP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Java code doesn't belong in a JSP.

If your intent is to gzip the HTML code generated by JSP, then you need to configure it at appserver level. In JBoss (and Tomcat) you need to set the `compression` attribute of the `<Connector>` element in `/server.xml` to `on`.

```
<Connector compression="on">
```

That's all. It'll be by default applied on all `text/*` responses (HTML/CSS/JS).

#### See also:

- [Tomcat 6.0 HTTP Connector configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html)
- [Web application performance tips and tricks](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html)

Comment: Hm, well I just tried altering the http connector in my jbossweb.sar/server.xml (I'm assuming to be the equivalent), and it seems to be working so far!

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, it'll work the same way on JBoss since its servletcontainer part is basically a slight modified fork of Tomcat. You can if necessary alter `compressableMimeTypes` whenever you want to cover more than only `text/*`, for example `application/json` which is in essence also text based response.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and also the link to your blog post was helpful too

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. This is a quick fix and quality information. However, is there anything I can do to gzip my content when I do not have access to the server files? On my local host this option is great but when I take my site to a godaddy shared VPS I will not have access to the server.xml file. Any pointers on what I could do then?

Comment: @gmu: You could use a servlet filter for this. The JSF utility library OmniFaces, which is maintained by me, has also such a filter which is also reusable on "plain" JSP/Servlet webapps and even in combination with other frameworks than JSF: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/GzipResponseFilter Other filters are listed in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4755302/

Comment: And your blog was a great read btw. It was nice seeing advice on how to make a website faster that was not geared towards the php developer.