# Exchange compressed data between web client and server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

On client side i am using jQuery and JSP and server side i am using Spring MVC. My question is can we send and receive data in compressed format i.e a client and server will exchange its data in a compressed format. How can i do that? please anybody explain me in brief. An example be too good.

Answer (score 1):

you can try GZIP-ing the response sent from the server. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827004/jsp-gzip-output-stream) might help .

sidenote: AFAIK, JSP is server side, not client side

Comment: JSP HTML/JS/CSS is client side, scriptlets, JSTL and other tags are executed at server side.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : HTML/JS/CSS is client side, and JSP can be used to generate them. But JSP itself is server side, it is in the same league with PHP or ASP. Please check the tag info for [JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info).

Comment: I never neglected that, just clarifying.