# How to receive and uncompress gzip data in java?

Tags: java, gzip, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I am sending data from my iPhone to server. Code is following:

```
      ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]; 
     [request setShouldCompressRequestBody:YES];   // gzip compression
     [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
     [request setPostValue:emailString forKey:@"email"]; 
     [request setPostValue:jsonStr forKey:@"jsonstring"];
     [request setPostValue:pwd forKey:@"password"];
     [request setDelegate:self]; 
     [request startAsynchronous];
```

I tried to search that how can i receive this data in my server but couldn't find any help. Will i receive it using req.getParameter(). If yes then what will be the parameter name and then how to unzip it and use email, jsonstring, password parameters. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (IMO) to do it in a standard J2EE environment is by using a GZIP compression filter. You can find some example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755302/which-compression-is-gzip-the-most-popular-servlet-filter-would-you-suggest) (although this one is only about response filter as far as I can see) or [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjl-comp-filter/) (this one, I believe, can also do request decompression which you asked about).

You then plug such a filter into your webapp by using a `<filter>` element in your `web.xml` (see [here](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Servlet_Filters/) for an example of how to use servlet filters), thus avoiding any hardcoded dependencies from your webapp's code.

Answer (score 0):

All you need here is some Servlet container like Tomcat (I don't think you need a whole Java EE environment unless your server applications is more complex, e.g. is distributed, JSP/Servet subset seems to be enough). It's a  server (both HTTP server and server in general, for any raw data) in essence where JSPs and Servlets do a request handling. By the way, Tomcat has a built-in gzip compression support which is simply configurable. So it should be easy.

Then you need to write a Servlet which extracts all parameters, mentioned in the client iOS code, from your HTTP request and construct and send a response. (There are a lot of articles, official documentation etc. about servlets) How they're extracted won't depend on whether you use GZIP or not, decompressions should be done before by a server.

**UPDATE**

As for parameter names, I guess (I'm not an iOS developer) they are strings right after 'setPostValue' message in your code, like
...
[request setPostValue:**emailString** forKey:@"email"];
...
So, they're currently

```
emailString
jsonStr
pwd
```

Summary, the reading code should be like this:

```
public abstract class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
  */
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String emailString = req.getParameter("emailString");
    String jsonStr = req.getParameter("jsonStr");
    String pwd = req.getParameter("pwd");
    //...       
  }
}
```