# How to compress output from a grails controller?

Tags: grails, http-compression

My Grails 1.3.7 controller is generating some JSON & I would like to send it to the client in compressed (zipped) form, as the amount of JSON can be 2+MB uncompressed. The resources plugin I found seems to compress static resources only. Is there a way to compress dynamic controller output as well?

Comment: Could [Ui-Performance](http://grails.org/plugin/ui-performance) plugin help? I am not sure about the usage but one of the feature of the plugin is to gzip dynamic text content like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need the below configuration in `Config.groovy` if [Ui-Performance plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/ui-performance) is used:

```
uiperformance.html.includeContentTypes = ['text/json','application/json']
```

Also have a look a [CompressingFilter API](http://pjl-comp-filter.sourceforge.net/com/planetj/servlet/filter/compression/CompressingFilter.html) which is used to compress HttpServletResponse.
If curious, you can also peep at the [source](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-ui-performance/blob/master/UiPerformanceGrailsPlugin.groovy) as to how the web descriptor is manipulated to use the compressor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving your grails application from behind a web-server like apache or nginx, you can configure the compression in the front-end rather easily.

See [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) for apache and [HttpGzipModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule) for nginx.

If you would rather do the compression work inside your jar, you can either create a `ServletFilter` and do the compression yourself [as mentioned in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755302/which-compression-is-gzip-the-most-popular-servlet-filter-would-you-suggest) or use something like the UI-Performance plugin [as mentioned by dmahapatro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17310184/459743).