# gzipping json response from grails controller

Tags: json, grails, controller, compression, gzip

I have a few really huge json responses being sent to the client browser, and I'm trying to figure out how to compress them. I've tried using the ui-performance plugin as described in an answer to this question:
[How to compress output from a grails controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309909/how-to-compress-output-from-a-grails-controller)

But it didn't work. My json file still is of the same size (~40MB)
I've also tried using the yui-minify resources plugin, but to no avail. How else can I do this?
Also, is it advisable to send such a huge json file to the browser? (A certain drop down selection on the front end lets the browser request a json response of this size each time the user selects an option)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Grails 3.0 and later are based on Spring Boot which enables this functionality. You should look at the docs for your individual version but in Grails 3.2.2 you can add this to the 2nd section of your `application.yml`:

```
server:
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

Comment: What's the 2nd section of my application.yml supposed to be? You mean under "spring:"?

Comment: Grails uses --- to split the configuration into sections (in accordance with the YAML spec), but without naming those parts it is a bit confusing where to put a setting. By 2nd section I mean anywhere after the first --- and before the second --- delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it directly in tomcat http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/

Either do it directly in `server.xml` or inside the `tomcat plugin`

UPDATE

you can also try doing it manually, smth like:

```
def zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream( response.outputStream )  
zipStream.write( yourJsonString.getBytes() )  
zipStream.close()  
response.outputStream
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this too. I added application/json, text/json to the mime types that should be gzipped. But it didn't work. Any reason why?

Comment: how are you testing? the compression can be visible in client only

Comment: On my Chrome dev tools, under network. As shown in the link you provided. There is no content-encoding header in my HTTP response.

Comment: what about the response content size?

Comment: It's still pretty big. Around 40 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Give the [Compress plugin](http://grails.org/Compress+Plugin) a try

Comment: Hey, no luck with that too. I added it(installed by including the code in BuildConfig.groovy, and tried it both with and without the code mentioned in the link you provided inside Config.groovy), but my application wouldn't load the json file itself. Threw me a 500 internal error once, and an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED the other time.

Comment: >> Last updated by mischa 5 years ago
that doesn't look good :/