# Enable Gzip compression in Websphere liberty profile

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

Is there a way to enable Gzip compression in Websphere liberty profile? I am running liberty profile from Eclipse Websphere developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP response compression is not a service provided by the container.  You have to add your own servlet filter to perform compression --  the question below lists some options:

[Which compression (is GZIP the most popular) servlet filter would you suggest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755302/which-compression-is-gzip-the-most-popular-servlet-filter-would-you-suggest)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** WebSphere Open Liberty now offers support for server side compression. See article here --> https://openliberty.io/blog/2020/04/22/http-response-compression.html
The IBM web page states:
"You can now configure Open Liberty (20.0.0.4+) to compress HTTP responses. Compressing the sizes of HTTP responses reduces bandwidth which, in turn, decreases the time taken for HTTP clients to get responses. Open Liberty first determines whether the response should be compressed then, if so, checks whether there is an encoding algorithm to perform the compression that is supported by the HTTP client."