# How to enable gzip/deflate compression on IBM WebSphere Application Server 6.1?

Tags: javascript, compression, websphere-6.1

I am using **IBM WebSphere Application Server 6.1** in my application. I want to make file like js, css and html to compress. My question is how can I enable compression?

**Note**

I am using **IBM WebSphere Application Server 6.1** not **IBM Http Server**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http compression is not available in WebSphere Application Server 6.1.
You may either add servlet filter to your application to do the cpmpression, see this post for some options [Which compression (is GZIP the most popular) servlet filter would you suggest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4755302/3701228)
or install and configure web server (IHS or Apache) for compression [Enabling data compression on an IBM HTTP Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21624766)

Comment: Does gzip compression support on IBM WebSphere Application Server 7?