# How to implement GZipFilter for JSF Application

Tags: java, jsf, gzip

Hi All iam currently working on performance improving of JSF 2.1 application . I tried the following link [Which compression (is GZIP the most popular) servlet filter would you suggest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755302/which-compression-is-gzip-the-most-popular-servlet-filter-would-you-suggest) , I am trying to implement on IBM Websphere but application is failing to start and show the error below. Do I miss any jars

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.utilities.CompressionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- FILTER MAPPINGS -->
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Error
C

```
aught Exception while handling event object with type : org.apache.webbeans.portable.events.generics.GProcessAnnotatedType
                                 javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException: Caught Exception while handling event object with type : org.apache.webbeans.portable.events.generics.GProcessAnnotatedType
    at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.fireEvent(NotificationManager.java:443)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:468)
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.WebBeansUtil.fireProcessAnnotatedTypeEvent(WebBeansUtil.java:2188)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploySingleAnnotatedType(BeansDeployer.java:595)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deployFromClassPath(BeansDeployer.java:540)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:172)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:157)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.WebBeansInitializer.onStartup(WebBeansInitializer.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2487)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:994)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6566)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:467)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:462)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1132)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:937)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.ModuleHandlerBase.deployModule(ModuleHandlerBase.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedModuleInfoImpl.installModule(DeployedModuleInfoImpl.java:49)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:429)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.ear.internal.EARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(EARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1258)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.performAction(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1138)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
Caused by: org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.webbeans.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.fireEvent(NotificationManager.java:429)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1061.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.apache.webbeans.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1061.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorHandler.invoke(InterceptorHandler.java:326)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:117)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.SecurityExtension_$$_javassist_47.processAnnotatedType(SecurityExtension_$$_javassist_47.java)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.WriteListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodsImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.impl.service.DefaultSecurityService$PrivilegedActionForClass.run(DefaultSecurityService.java:260)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.impl.service.DefaultSecurityService.doPrivilegedGetDeclaredMethods(DefaultSecurityService.java:166)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AnnotatedTypeImpl.init(AnnotatedTypeImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AnnotatedTypeImpl.getMethods(AnnotatedTypeImpl.java:207)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.SecurityExtension.processAnnotatedType(SecurityExtension.java:103)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.WriteListener
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:924)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:869)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:482)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:443)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: Try https://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/GzipResponseFilter

Comment: thank you i found out the reason added javax-servlet-api eclipse jetty jar now its working perfectly